# Return value of a C function to ASM

Tags: c, assembly, nasm, osdev

I'm trying to call a function from within ASM. I know how to call it, but i'm having trouble finding how to get the return value of this function. An example follows:

**C code:**

```
int dummy() {  
    return 5;  
}
```

**(N)ASM code:**

```
dummyFunction:
    call dummy
    ;grab return into eax
    inc eax ; eax should be 6 now
    ret
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What kind of "trouble" you're having?

Comment: Indeed, tell us what's going wrong...

Comment: @R.. I think his problem is just, that he doesn't know that `eax` is already set correctly.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The return value is in `eax`. If you've called a C function from asm, you can read the return value from `eax`. If you're trying to return from an asm function to C, store the intended return value in `eax`.

Things get a little bit more complicated for returning floating point values, `long long` values, or structures, so ask if you need that and someone (maybe me) will help you.

Answer (score 13):

Although the answers are sufficient to answer the OP's question, here's an extract covering most cases from [DJGPP's manpage](https://web.archive.org/web/20140708065738/www.delorie.com/djgpp/doc/ug/asm/calling.html#retval) for completeness:

> #### Return Value
>
> - Integers (of any size up to 32 bits) and pointers are returned in the `%eax` register.
> - Floating point values are returned in the 387 top-of-stack register, `st(0)`.
> - Return values of type `long long int` are returned in `%edx:%eax` (the most significant word in `%edx` and the least significant in `%eax`).
> - Returning a structure is complicated and rarely useful; try to avoid it. (Note that this is different from returning a pointer to a structure.)
>
> If your function returns `void` (e.g. no value), the contents of these registers are not used.

Comment: The link seems to be dead. Here's a link to an archive on the Internet Archive: https://web.archive.org/web/20140708065738/www.delorie.com/djgpp/doc/ug/asm/calling.html

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the platform and the calling convention, but usually, the return value should already be returned in `eax` if it's a primitive type or pointer and in the floating point register `st(0)` if it's a floating point type, I think.

Comment: +1 Yes, if it's a floating-point type, then it's returned via `st(0)`; see my answer.