# determining the return type of a function in assembly

Tags: c, assembly, return-type

The code below is a homework assignment, the actual assembly commands I understand. However I am unsure (and have been looking) how to determine the return type of the function and how many arguments if any the function takes. Professor really didn't go over this well (Monotone tenure princess) 
The assignment is to read assembly code and then write c code base on the assembly code. Again I understand the instructions, just cant figure out what the return type is or how many arguments the code takes

```
    .file   "hw5.c"
    .text
    .p2align 4,,15
.globl p1
    .type   p1, @function
p1:
.LFB0:
    .cfi_startproc
    addq    %rsi, %rdi
    addq    %rdi, %rdx
    movq    %rdx, %rax
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
```

Comment: 'Monotone tenure princess' lol, have an upvote just for that:)

Comment: Assembly has no concept of a "return type", nor an "argument".

Comment: can you further explain @immibis ? if such is the case I find it difficult to understand how I would write a meaningful function based on the assembly. I know now from this question asked, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6171172/return-value-of-a-c-function-to-asm that the register being used to return can help determine the return type, I am still working on the arguments.

Comment: Assembly language has a *calling convention* which you use to determine what is passed above. You see `rdi`, `rsi` and `rdx` used. It just so happens, the 64-bit calling convention uses the first six integer arguments (from the left) which are passed in RDI, RSI, RDX, RCX, R8, and R9, in that order. So there are 3 arguments passed to your function in RDI, RSI, and RDX.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin that is good news, thats what I was starting to think! Thank you.

Comment: @ChristopherJakob I mean exactly what I said - there is no such thing as a return type, or an argument, in assembly. C has them, but assembly doesn't. And you can do certain things in assembly that have the effect of passing arguments or return values in C. But those are to do with the way C is translated to assembly, not assembly itself.

Comment: This is, I think, an unfair assignment. You could write C code which would produce equivalent assembly when compiled, but as to the argument types, who can say? maybe `int`, maybe `unsigned int`, maybe something else...

Comment: @immibis that is something I know, thank you for the insight. I should have reworded my question. What I was trying to say is how can I translate a C return statement and arguments passed from assembly. I see now that its in the calling convention and return register.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look at the calling convention for the processor/platform to understand the low level implementation.

Before calling a subroutine, the caller should save the contents of certain registers that are designated caller-saved. The caller-saved registers are EAX, ECX, EDX[x86]. Since the called subroutine is allowed to modify these registers, if the caller relies on their values after the subroutine returns, the caller must push the values in these registers onto the stack (so they can be restore after the subroutine returns.
To pass parameters to the subroutine, push them onto the stack before the call. The parameters should be pushed in inverted order (i.e. last parameter first). Since the stack grows down, the first parameter will be stored at the lowest address (this inversion of parameters was historically used to allow functions to be passed a variable number of parameters). [ from x86 calling convention]

Comment: The 2nd paragraph isn't really relevant here, this is a leaf function and it's only using registers that hold its args.

Comment: The assembly is quite obviously using `x86-64`, which has different calling conventions entirely.

Answer (score 2):

See https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info for links to calling convention docs.  This looks like the standard SysV x86 ABI, used by everything except Windows.

This is obviously doing two adds 64bit adds to generate a result from three input registers, then putting the result in `%rax`.

You can't tell whether the result is signed or unsigned, though, because the code would be the same.

Also, an optimized version would skip the `mov` by using `lea` as a non-destructive add with an output that wasn't one of the inputs:

```
lea  (%rdi,%rdx), %rax
```

Comment: Clearly from the output it is Redhat Linux ;-)

Comment: @MichaelPetch: Are you making fun of my "obviously"?  That's fair. :)  I sometimes get annoyed with "easy" questions and talk down in reply to them.  By the time I've read the question to see if it's really as simple as it appears, I already have a reply in mind.  Often I start it as a comment, then realize that it's turned into an answer, and post it as such.

Comment: I placed a winky smiley face on the end. I was just joking around. You may say why I chose Redhat Linux. Can't tell from the code presented but I happened to notice this: https://ideone.com/nuu1Ao (the very bottom suggests output was Redhat). I went searching because I thought something might have been missing from the question.

Comment: @MichaelPetch: I knew you were joking around, but I couldn't figure out what the joke was >.<  Interesting find, that might well be what this code is taken from.  I wonder what the compile options were for that.  Maybe `-O1`?    `p2` in that file uses the unsigned-compare trick (so probably not `-O0`), but `p3` looks badly optimized (it could be `imul $100, %edi, %eax` / `add %esi, %eax`).

Comment: It is generated code, but I'm not quite sure what compile option but part seems optimized and part doesn't. So higher than `-O0` and the age of the compiler might explain some poor/missed optimizations. I'd guess `-O1` too.

Comment: @PeterCordes apparently is a goddess, how dare I ask a question the goddess deems easy. How about this princess if you deem a question to be easy, don't answer it. Isn't that better? Or are you slave to the rep score?

Comment: @ChristopherJakob: That wasn't all directed at this question.  I think I'd just read a few even more boring questions, which I did skip, and was slightly grumpy.  I thought that it was obvious that the `add` instructions were operating on three inputs, since the destination is read and written. (unlike `mov`, where the dest is write-only).  This is not a bad question because there is a non-obvious part: *why* does it make sense for a function to use those registers.  That's the part worth answering (by identifying which calling convention it was using), esp. since another answer was wrong.

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 arguments. They are rsi, rdi and rdx. Return value is in rax. Function sums the three arguments. Arguments can be signed or unsigned, as Addq works with both. All arguments and return value should be considered to have same type (signed or unsigned 64 bit integers).

This is a calling convention I've never seen on x64. So after converting to C the compiler won't generate the same assembly unless you specify a custom calling convention (assuming the compiler supports that).

Once you define a calling convention you can say what the order of the arguments is. Until then you don't know if rsi/rdi/rdx is first, second, or third arg.

Comment: It's the SysV calling convention, used by everything but Windows. (Linux, OS X, Solaris, etc.)

Comment: There is a defined calling convention for X86_64, so you do know what the order is.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I didn't know the calling convention (SysV). Without that I couldn't say what the order of args is. BTW there isn't a single x86_64 calling convention as Peter points outs.

Comment: I understand, that's why you didn't get dinged for it `:)`

Answer (score 0):

this post, answers my question for the most part. [Return value of a C function to ASM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6171172/return-value-of-a-c-function-to-asm) I didn't see this until I completely rethought my search word choice. I still am trying to figure out the number of arguments passed into the function. if I am correct though `

```
addq    %rsi, %rdi
addq    %rdi, %rdx
```

these two lines show me that two aguments  are passed. one is stored in `&rsi` the other stored in `%rdi`

Comment: "addq %rdi, %rdx" adds rdi to rdx. Where do you suppose the initial value of rdx comes from? (Hint: you may be wrong about it being only two arguments).

Comment: @davmac yep, you're right, I noticed that it was three when I realized I was being silly about the second add command. Thank you!

Comment: @ChristopherJakob Look into the [System V ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#System_V_AMD64_ABI), it describes which argument is what register.