# Writing a C program from Assembly language

Tags: c, gcc, assembly

I'm attempting to learn assembly language and I'm not sure if I'm on the right track. I have a program in assembly language that I need to convert to C.

```
addq    %rsi, %rdi
addq    %rdi, %rdx
movq    %rdx, %rax
ret
```

Trying to work through it myself I come up with something along the lines of

```
long p1(long x, long y, long z)
{
 x = x + y;
 z = z + x;
 long a = z;
 return a;
}
```

No matter which way I look at it I feel like I'm close but when I objdump I get nothing of the sort. Looking for some guidance.. thanks!

Comment: Go the other way. `gcc -S ur_c.c` will produce assembly output to look at.

Comment: please edit the code. `{` should be `}`. Is there any compile error with your code ?

Comment: That's what I've been attempting but the assembly output doesn't match the problem. I don't think I'm way off but maybe I am?

Comment: There is no guarantee that an arbitrary sequence of assembler statements must have a `C` counterpart which, when compiled, would generate the exact same sequence. In fact, that's provably false with any reasonable assumptions. Instead, what are you *actually* trying to do or figure out?

Comment: The assignment is to take assembly code and write a C program that functions the same. Maybe I'm trying to be too specific?

Comment: `functions the same` does _not_ mean _compile to the same exact assembly_.

Comment: You know.. as I was typing that I realized my mistake. I believe I'm just being paranoid but damn do I love stack for the quick responses :P

Comment: I'm not marking this as duplicate, but I wish to point out that there was another question related to this assignment here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/35468163/3857942

Answer (score 3):

Your C code looks fine, and as far as I can tell, it does the same thing as your assembly code.

You shouldn't necessarily expect that compiling your C code will give exactly the same assembly as the example.  There are many different ways to convert C into assembly.

For instance, if I compile your C code with `gcc -O0` (no optimization), I get much longer assembly, which stores all the function arguments and variables onto the stack.  This is unnecessary (and slower) but makes things easier for a debugger.  If I compile with `gcc -O2`, I get

```
    leaq    (%rdi,%rsi), %rax
    addq    %rdx, %rax
    ret
```

Here the compiler has made clever use of the [`lea` instruction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1658294/whats-the-purpose-of-the-lea-instruction) to do an addition and a move in one instruction.

Comment: Ahh, that's where my confusion came in. I imagined that I could have it disassemble the same if I were to give it the correct C code.

Comment: That being said it would be the same thing to simplify it and make it
    long a = x + y + z; 

correct?

Comment: @Ben: Yep, or even the one line `return x+y+z;`

Comment: Really appreciate the help. I was hoping that was the case but I was having trouble finding information as to whether assembly/c lined up that specifically.